# id IN (list of other ids) depending on IFs

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have an easy join like:

```
SELECT field.table1, field.table2 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.table1 = table1.id
FROM table1
WHERE table1.id = [changing id];
```

Where table1.id is the autoincrement index and table2.table1 is the 1:n key from table1 to table2.

Now I need to do something like:

```
SELECT field.table1, field.table2 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON 
[   IF table1.id = 1 THEN table2.table1 IN (10, 11, 12)
    IF table1.id = 2 THEN table2.table1 IN (13, 14)
    IF table1.id = 3 THEN table2.table1 IN (15)
    IF table1.id = 4 THEN table2.table1 IN (16, 17, 18)]
FROM table1
WHERE table1.id = [changing id];
```

Whats the correct syntax to do so?

Please keep in mind that this is just an example. There are reasons why I need to do it this way (the connotations 1 => 10,11,12, 2 => 13,14 and so on are not coming from the DB / the hole query is dynamically fed into another system which I can't change and where the query is done, so I do not know the id at this moment).

Comment: `and ((table1.id = 1 AND table2.table1 IN (10, 11, 12)) OR (table1.id = 2 AND table2.table1 IN (13, 14)) OR ...`

Comment: While it's entirely possible to do, I really feel this is one of those cases where some background on what your real goal is would make this a lot easier to find a good solution for. Because generally you shouldn't be bouncing around like this, and it will lead to very poor user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax should be a series of logical (AND \ OR) clauses:

```
SELECT field.table1, field.table2 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON 
   (table1.id = 1 AND table2.table1 IN (10, 11, 12) )
OR (table1.id = 2 AND table2.table1 IN (13, 14) )
OR (table1.id = 3 AND table2.table1 IN (15) ) 
FROM table1
WHERE table1.id = [changing id];
```

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is create a mapping table, like so (we'll call it `table3`):

| Table1ID | Table2ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 13 |
| 2 | 14 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 4 | 16 |
| 4 | 17 |
| 4 | 18 |

And then add another level for joins:

```
SELECT field.table1, field.table2 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.Table1ID = table1.id
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table3.table2ID
WHERE table1.id = [changing id];
```